Light fixture - three sets of wires and no switch
I am replacing the light fixture in my kitchen. There were 3 black wires bundled together and 3 white wires bundled together, and were attached to the respective black and white wires in old fixture, no ground. We when we removed the junction box (too small) we see it is three sets of black and white wires in fabric sheathing.
The house is 100 yrs old, and kitchen is an addition built in the 50-60s. Wiring is updated from knob and tube to a panel. The fixture being replaced was a pull chain, no switch attached that we are aware of. What do I do with this?


Should have one hot cable from the panel and two cables going/supplying power to other stuff.  Can replace with a light fixture with a pull chain switch or a smart bulb or rewire to a wall switch.

So it is acting like a daisy chain to carry power from the box? Thanks, wondered this after I posted!

You'll need a new junction box up there. It would be a good idea to install one that's ceiling fan rated in case you decide to install a fan and light fixture with pull chains since it appears you don't have a switch. You can use a junction box and bracket similar to the one pictures below from Lowes who I'm not affiliated with.

You'll also need a few NM two screw cable clamps to secure your wires from the ceiling into the junction box.  Wire nut your three black wires together with the black wire from your new fixture and the three white wires together with the white wire from your new fixture.
In the future, it's always a good idea to take a few pictures of your project before disconnecting any wires.

Thanks! We unfortunately are stuck with a bar already up there that the old junction box was attached to. We think we found some conduit brackets to attach a new junction box around the existing steel bar. We were able to identify what all three wires go to and labeled them (from the panel, the overhead light and to an outlet that isn’t used.) This also explained why the switches don’t work…they are wired to the overhead light after the power flows from the sink light. Putting in the new box this weekend.
